# Convert integer into byte array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, integer, byte

what's a fast way to convert an `Integer` into a `Byte Array`?

e.g. `0xAABBCCDD => {AA, BB, CC, DD}`

Comment: Does it matter what format the resulting byte array is? What will you do with it?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Have a look at the [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/class-use/ByteBuffer.html) class.

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
//b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN); // optional, the initial order of a byte buffer is always BIG_ENDIAN.
b.putInt(0xAABBCCDD);

byte[] result = b.array();
```

Setting the byte order ensures that `result[0] == 0xAA`, `result[1] == 0xBB`, `result[2] == 0xCC` and `result[3] == 0xDD`.

Or alternatively, you could do it manually:

```
byte[] toBytes(int i)
{
  byte[] result = new byte[4];

  result[0] = (byte) (i >> 24);
  result[1] = (byte) (i >> 16);
  result[2] = (byte) (i >> 8);
  result[3] = (byte) (i /*>> 0*/);

  return result;
}
```

The `ByteBuffer` class was designed for such dirty hands tasks though. In fact the private `java.nio.Bits` defines these helper methods that are used by `ByteBuffer.putInt()`:

```
private static byte int3(int x) { return (byte)(x >> 24); }
private static byte int2(int x) { return (byte)(x >> 16); }
private static byte int1(int x) { return (byte)(x >>  8); }
private static byte int0(int x) { return (byte)(x >>  0); }
```

Comment: this would work well if the bytebuffer is already there... otherwise it seems like it would take longer to do the allocation, than to just allocate a byte array of length 4 and do the shifting manually... but we're probably talking about small differences.

Comment: The ByteBuffer instance can be cached; and internally it's surely implemented with shifting and masking anyway.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine answer.  Note that big-endian is the specified default, and the methods are "chainable", and the position argument is optional, so it all reduces to:

byte[] result = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(0xAABBCCDD).array();

Of course, if you're doing this repeatedly and concatenating all the results together (which is common when you're doing this kind of thing), allocate a single buffer and repeatedly putFoo() all the things into it that you need -- it will keep track of the offset as you go. It's really a tremendously useful class.

Comment: what does it bring on signed types?

Comment: If you plan on using that ByteBuffer in subsequent NIO writing operations, you will need to `rewind` it. Otherwise, you won't write anything! (Been there, done that!)

Comment: For who doesn't know. The putInt will always write 4 bytes, no matter what size the input integer is. If you only want 2 bytes, use putShort, etc ...

Answer (score 47):

Using `BigInteger`:

```
private byte[] bigIntToByteArray( final int i ) {
    BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(i);      
    return bigInt.toByteArray();
}
```

Using `DataOutputStream`:

```
private byte[] intToByteArray ( final int i ) throws IOException {      
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    dos.writeInt(i);
    dos.flush();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Using `ByteBuffer`:

```
public byte[] intToBytes( final int i ) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4); 
    bb.putInt(i); 
    return bb.array();
}
```

Comment: pay attention to the byte order though

Comment: Does ByteBuffer gives out an unsigned int?

Comment: @Pascal Using ByteBuffer I tried with  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(3); For this it is giving java.nio.BufferOverflowException, I am not getting why it is not working for value less than 4? Can you please explain?

Comment: @SanjayJain You get a buffer overflow exception because ints in Java are 32-bits or 4 bytes in size, and therefore require you to allocate at least 4 bytes of memory in your ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 32):

use this function it works for me

```
public byte[] toByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[] {
            (byte)(value >> 24),
            (byte)(value >> 16),
            (byte)(value >> 8),
            (byte)value};
}
```

it translates the int into a byte value

Comment: It's also worth nothing that this will work regardless of the most significant bit and more efficient compared to the other answers. Also could use '>>'.

Comment: A direct solution like this is certainly faster than calling any library method. Sometimes you just have to fiddle with the the bits directly with a few lines of code rather than incurring all the extra overhead of library method calls.

Comment: And this converts between languages well so is good for multi language software development.

Answer (score 17):

If you like [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you may use its [`Ints`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v14.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) class:

---

For `int` → `byte[]`, use [`toByteArray()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toByteArray%28int%29):

```
byte[] byteArray = Ints.toByteArray(0xAABBCCDD);
```

Result is `{0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD}`.

---

Its reverse is [`fromByteArray()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#fromByteArray%28byte%5b%5d%29) or [`fromBytes()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#fromBytes%28byte,%20byte,%20byte,%20byte%29):

```
int intValue = Ints.fromByteArray(new byte[]{(byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xCC, (byte) 0xDD});
int intValue = Ints.fromBytes((byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xCC, (byte) 0xDD);
```

Result is `0xAABBCCDD`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `BigInteger`:

From Integers:

```
byte[] array = BigInteger.valueOf(0xAABBCCDD).toByteArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))
// --> {-86, -69, -52, -35 }
```

The returned array is of the size that is needed to represent the number, so it could be of size 1, to represent 1 for example.  However, the size cannot be more than four bytes if an int is passed.

From Strings:

```
BigInteger v = new BigInteger("AABBCCDD", 16);
byte[] array = v.toByteArray();
```

However, you will need to watch out, if the first byte is higher `0x7F` (as is in this case), where BigInteger would insert a 0x00 byte to the beginning of the array.  This is needed to distinguish between positive and negative values.

Comment: thanks!
But since this is BigInteger, will ints wrap around correctly? That is integers that are outside Integer.MAX_VALUE but can still be represented with only 4 bytes?

Comment: This is certainly not fast to execute. ;)

Comment: This is not a good option. Not only it may add 0x00 byte, it may also strip leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Can also shift -

```
byte[] ba = new byte[4];
int val = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(byte i=0;i<4;i++)
    ba[i] = (byte)(val >> i*8);
    //ba[3-i] = (byte)(val >> i*8); //Big-endian
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution which properly handles ByteOrder:

`ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).putInt(yourInt).array();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that should do the job just right.

```
public byte[] toByteArray(int value)
{
    final byte[] destination = new byte[Integer.BYTES];
    for(int index = Integer.BYTES - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        destination[i] = (byte) value;
        value = value >> 8;
    };
    return destination;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte [] hbhbytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(16666666).array();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hbhbytes));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very easy with android

```
int i=10000;
byte b1=(byte)Color.alpha(i);
byte b2=(byte)Color.red(i);
byte b3=(byte)Color.green(i);
byte b4=(byte)Color.blue(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's my solution:

```
public void getBytes(int val) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[Integer.BYTES];
    for (int i = 0;i < bytes.length; i ++) {
        int j = val % Byte.MAX_VALUE;
        bytes[i] = (j == 0 ? Byte.MAX_VALUE : j);
    }
}
```

Also `String`y method:

```
public void getBytes(int val) {
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(val);
    byte[] val = new byte[hex.length()/2]; // because byte is 2 hex chars
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2)
        val[i] = Byte.parseByte("0x" + hex.substring(i, i+2), 16);
    return val;
}
```