# Java integer to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, byte

I got an integer: `1695609641`

when I use method:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(1695609641);
system.out.println(hex);
```

gives:

```
6510f329
```

but I want a byte array:

```
byte[] bytearray = new byte[] { (byte) 0x65, (byte)0x10, (byte)0xf3, (byte)0x29};
```

How can I make this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert integer into byte array (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer into byte array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java)

Answer (score 351, accepted):

using Java NIO's [ByteBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) is very simple:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(1695609641).array();

for (byte b : bytes) {
   System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
}
```

output:

```
0x65 0x10 0xf3 0x29
```

Comment: Or use the format `"0x%02X"` if you always want two hexadecimal characters as well as uppercase hexadecimals, e.g. `System.out.format("0x%02X", (byte) 10)` displays `0x0A`.

Comment: ByteBuffer.allocate() doesn't seem to exist but allocateDirect() does. I'm going with that.

Comment: @conor Javadoc says that allocateDirect() does have a cost and should be used when a buffer is kept for a while. Although the answer works it seems to be a bit of overkill for the use case at hand.

Comment: You can use Integer.SIZE/8 to avoid hardcoding the 4, which is a pattern that works well for other types like Long.

Comment: What is 0x%x in here?

Comment: @davenpcj You can even use Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE

Comment: @rkosegi Or even Integer.BYTES since Java 8 :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thread has nothing to visible formatting, but native type operation

Comment: in fact putInt(0, i) is faster because ByteBuffer doesn't update internal indexes

Comment: java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Comment: Watch out: in java the bytes are in reverse order of what it is in .NET: for example for 75 in java you will get bytes 75,0,0,0. BitConverter in .NET will produce 0,0,0,75 for 75. Just killed a lot of time on this...

Answer (score 188):

How about:

```
public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[] {
            (byte)(value >>> 24),
            (byte)(value >>> 16),
            (byte)(value >>> 8),
            (byte)value};
}
```

The idea is *not mine*. I've taken it from [some post on dzone.com](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/93).

Comment: -1 Not a good idea to hand-code things like this; that's what properly-tested and reviewed JDK libraries are for.

Comment: I see your point, but for this particular task 'my' code is more declarative and clear than some 'magic' ByteBuffer, which one has to check to see what it does.

Comment: @Kevin - that's very harsh - there are plenty of cases where this kind of code is appropriate, e.g. in image processing. The JDK libraries are great in general, but they don't cover and/or aren't optimised for all use cases.

Comment: agreed; the overhead and complexity of ByteBuffer may not be appropriate compared to some simple and well known byte operations.

Comment: Another point I'd add is that you've used the unsigned right shift operator `>>>` rather than the right shift operator `>>` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) so behavior may not be as desired/as expected with signed vs unsigned numbers

Comment: This approach seems to be a tad faster than the ByteBuffer or BigInteger methods mentioned.
Something else to take into account if you will be doing a lot of conversions.

Comment: +1, this solution also works for J2ME, where ByteBuffer (accepted answer) may not be available.

Comment: Code to go back to integer again is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5399829/418057

Comment: Note: this is BigEndian. If you need LittleEndian you have to reverse the order.

Comment: some post on dzone.com: Does not exist anymore

Comment: @RobV Because of the cast to `(byte)`, the flavor of the shift won't matter in this case. If the number of bits-shifted were not a multiple of 8 in each case, there *would* be a difference.

Answer (score 57):

`BigInteger.valueOf(1695609641).toByteArray()`

Comment: what guarantee do you have that that will produce a 4 byte array?

Comment: Exactly what MeBigFatGuy wrote. Javadoc of `BigInteger.toByteArray()` states: "The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger..."

Comment: Where in the question does it ask for the byte array to be of fixed length 4?

Depending on algorithm this is meant to be part of you can utilize the length of the array

Comment: this is much more dynamic and should be the right answer. You can simply do an Array append to create the desired size if you like. Specially when you have to consider Java signed int values.

Comment: This seems to create one byte for 0x7f and two bytes for 0x80  ( the two bytes being: 0x0 0x80 ).

Comment: yeah it must be converting to the two's-compliment interpretation of the number

Answer (score 33):

```
byte[] IntToByteArray( int data ) {    
    byte[] result = new byte[4];
    result[0] = (byte) ((data & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
    result[1] = (byte) ((data & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    result[2] = (byte) ((data & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
    result[3] = (byte) ((data & 0x000000FF) >> 0);
    return result;        
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
byte[] bytearray = Ints.toByteArray(1695609641);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
byte[] conv = new byte[4];
conv[3] = (byte) input & 0xff;
input >>= 8;
conv[2] = (byte) input & 0xff;
input >>= 8;
conv[1] = (byte) input & 0xff;
input >>= 8;
conv[0] = (byte) input;
```

Comment: That extracts the least significant 8 bytes. It also avoids dragging the input number's sign into the converted octet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305634/how-to-write-this-c-sharp-four-bytes-of-length-info-in-java - can you please solve this C# into Java?

Answer (score 7):

```
public static byte[] intToBytes(int x) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeInt(x);
    out.close();
    byte[] int_bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    return int_bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because generally you would want to convert this array back to an int at a later point, here are the methods to convert an array of ints into an array of bytes and vice-versa:

```
public static byte[] convertToByteArray(final int[] pIntArray)
{
    final byte[] array = new byte[pIntArray.length * 4];
    for (int j = 0; j < pIntArray.length; j++)
    {
        final int c = pIntArray[j];
        array[j * 4] = (byte)((c & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
        array[j * 4 + 1] = (byte)((c & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
        array[j * 4 + 2] = (byte)((c & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        array[j * 4 + 3] = (byte)(c & 0xFF);
    }
    return array;
}

public static int[] convertToIntArray(final byte[] pByteArray)
{
    final int[] array = new int[pByteArray.length / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = (((int)(pByteArray[i * 4]) << 24) & 0xFF000000) |
                (((int)(pByteArray[i * 4 + 1]) << 16) & 0xFF0000) |
                (((int)(pByteArray[i * 4 + 2]) << 8) & 0xFF00) |
                ((int)(pByteArray[i * 4 + 3]) & 0xFF);
    return array;
}
```

Note that because of sign propagation and such, the "& 0xFF..." are needed when converting back to the int.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [apache-commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Conversion.html#intToByteArray-int-int-byte:A-int-int-)

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(int value) {
    byte result[] = new byte[4];
    return Conversion.intToByteArray(value, 0, result, 0, 4);
}
```

Comment: This would be good but "Conversion" is in Apache Commons Lang 3 which is for Java 8+. Unfortunately I still require Java 7 compatibility :(

Answer (score 2):

```
integer & 0xFF
```

for the first byte

```
(integer >> 8) & 0xFF
```

for the second and loop etc., writing into a preallocated byte array. A bit messy, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The chunks below work at least for sending an int over UDP.

int to byte array:

```
public byte[] intToBytes(int my_int) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeInt(my_int);
    out.close();
    byte[] int_bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    return int_bytes;
}
```

byte array to int:

```
public int bytesToInt(byte[] int_bytes) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(int_bytes);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    int my_int = ois.readInt();
    ois.close();
    return my_int;
}
```

Comment: use of ObjectOutputStream is incorrect. Use DataOutputStream, use of OOS makes it so the byte array is not 4 bytes.

Comment: MeBigFatGuy is correct. The bytes array includes other bytes as well, surely more than 4 expected.

Answer (score 1):

The class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes has a bunch of handy byte[] conversion methods, but you might not want to add the whole HBase jar to your project just for this purpose. It's surprising that not only are such method missing AFAIK from the JDK, but also from obvious libs like commons io.

Answer (score 1):

My try :

```
public static byte[] toBytes(final int intVal, final int... intArray) {
    if (intArray == null || (intArray.length == 0)) {
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(intVal).array();
    } else {
        final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + (intArray.length * 4)).putInt(intVal);
        for (final int val : intArray) {
            bb.putInt(val);
        }
        return bb.array();
    }
}
```

With it you can do this :

```
byte[] fourBytes = toBytes(0x01020304);
byte[] eightBytes = toBytes(0x01020304, 0x05060708);
```

Full class is here : https://gist.github.com/superbob/6548493, it supports initialization from shorts or long

```
byte[] eightBytesAgain = toBytes(0x0102030405060708L);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two function to do the mirrored thing:

```java
    byte[] intToBytes(int i) {
        return new byte[]{
                (byte) (i >>> 24),
                (byte) (i >>> 16),
                (byte) (i >>> 8),
                (byte) i
        };
    }
```

```java
    int bytesToInt(byte[] b) {
        //Cuz int encode by complement-on-two
        //For a negative, signed left shift operation will Fill the upper part of the binary with 1.
        //That‘s a question for us to combine the meaningful part.

        //Here, we execute a AND 0xFF operation, to implicitly convert a byte to int, and fill  the upper part of the binary with 0
        //So ,we got a positive number now.
        //The next step just execute OR operation to combine the four part as an integer.
        return (b[0]) << 24 |
                (b[1] & 0xFF) << 16 |
                (b[2] & 0xFF) << 8 |
                (b[3] & 0xFF);
    }
```