# Interpreting same bits-sequence as different datatypes

Tags: java, types, memory-management

Can we read a same sequence of bytes as different data-types in java? I was wondering if that is possible. The purpose is to demonstrate the representation of different data-types in memory, specifically Java.

Comment: If possible do this in C, pointer type casting is _EXACTLY_ what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a `double` to and from `long` preserving its binary representation (rather than value) using the following methods: `doubleToLongBits()`, `doubleToRawLongBits()` and `longBitsToDouble()`.

You can also use [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) like this:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ByteShow {
  public static void showBytes(ByteBuffer bb) {
    byte[] bytes = bb.array();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
      System.out.format("0x02%x ", b);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    showBytes(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(0x12345678));
    showBytes(ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putDouble(Math.PI))
    showBytes(ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putChar('@'));
  }
}
```

which outputs:

```
0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 
0x40 0x09 0x21 0xfb 0x54 0x44 0x2d 0x18 
0x00 0x40
```

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array).

Comment: This last part(main function) you added is exactly what I wanted, could not clearly mention in the question though... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Union](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/io/Union.html) type in [Javolution](http://javolution.org/) ;)