# Java integer to byte array Blackberry J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, type-conversion, blackberry-jde

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array) solution but it seems to be for Java SE. I can't find an alternative to the System.out.format() function. Also, I have changed the `ByteBuffer.allocate()` function to `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` is this correct?

```
    byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(1695609641).array();

    for (byte b : bytes) {
         System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want [network byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking) aka big-endian order which is used throughout Java's serialization and remoting libraries:

```
static byte[] intToBytesBigEndian(int i) {
  return new byte[] {
    (byte) ((i >>> 24) & 0xff),
    (byte) ((i >>> 16) & 0xff),
    (byte) ((i >>> 8) & 0xff),
    (byte) (i & 0xff),
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 32-bit integer = 4 bytes (8 bits each)
int i = 1695609641;
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

// big-endian, store most significant byte in byte 0
byte[3] = (byte)(i & 0xff);
i >>= 8;
byte[2] = (byte)(i & 0xff);
i >>= 8;
byte[1] = (byte)(i & 0xff);
i >>= 8;
byte[0] = (byte)(i & 0xff);
```