# How to convert an Integer into a formatted 4-Byte Hexidecimal (with leading 0's)

Tags: java, integer, hex, formatted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java integer to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array)

### **Here's another question still related to the original below:**

If I have a hex number that takes up 4 characters (2-bytes) saved as an integer.
Example:

```
int value = 0xFFFF;
```

This in java will make it a 4-byte hex with 2 bytes being completely empty.

How am I able to grab only the two bytes that have data?

Help is greatly appreciated! :)

### **Answer to my second question:**

Better answer posted below by md_5.

> So to get the SINGLE byte that has data you can simply do: byte single
>   = (byte) i & 0xFF If you had a bigger number up to 65535 (0xFFFF) you can do:
>
> ```
> byte b1 = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF); 
> byte b2 = (byte) i & 0xFF
> ```
>
> If you had an even larger number in the integer range you just do b1 =
>   i >> 24, b2 = i >> 16, etc etc etc. Subtracting 8 from the shift as
>   that is the size of a byte.

An alternate method uses the answer to the original question:

```
int hex = 0xF15E;
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(hex).array();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.format("0x%X ", bytes[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
0x0 0x0 0xF1 0x5E
```

So then take the important bytes:

```
byte[] importantBytes = {bytes[2], bytes[3]};
```

---

### **Original Question:**

This question may be obsolete due to being able to converting an Integer into a byte[] but here goes:

How does one convert an integer into a hexidecimal that has leading 0's?

So if I have the integer: 4096, in hex would be 00001000.

The overall purpose was to then convert this formatted hex string into a byte[] (which would then be saved), but I think I can do this by the means above.

But still... How do we convert this integer into a formatted hex string? Is this even practical?

The language of preference is Java, and I looked at Integer.toHexString().

### **Working solution for what I originally needed:**

```
int value = 2147483647;
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
System.out.format("0x%X ", bytes[i]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert this formatted hex string into a byte[]"? One character in Java does not fit into a byte...

Comment: Yea I realized 1 character is 1/2 a byte.  The reason I say it's formatted because I want something that could possibly be 2 bytes to take up four (filling the unused ones with 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your new question (getting the bytes that have data), you are wrong in saying that it takes up 2 bytes, 0xFF can in fact be packed into one byte.
Long/Double - 8 bytes
Integer/Float - 4 bytes
Short - 2 bytes
Byte - 1 byte

So to get the SINGLE byte that has data you can simply do:
`byte single = (byte) i & 0xFF`
If you had a bigger number up to 65535 (0xFFFF) you can do:
`byte b1 = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF); byte b2 = (byte) i & 0xFF`
If you had an even larger number in the integer range you just do b1 = i >> 24, b2 = i >> 16, etc etc etc. Subtracting 8 from the shift as that is the size of a byte.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I made an oopsies. So yes, I was wrong. The integer should've been "0xFFFF"  Thank you for being smart and forseeing this mistake of mine! :D Great answer (which was what I was actually looking for instead of my other solution marked up there)!

Comment: Awesome, its amazing where a little bit of bit shifting can get you in life.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), or one of its convenience wrappers like [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)  e.g.:

```
String str = String.format("%08x", val);
```

This will give you a `String`, but I'll leave it to you to get that into a `byte[]`...