# how to cast int to byte[] and recast the value from byte[]

Tags: java

I thought that the casting between int and byte[] is so easy and I have tried to cast a value to byte[] and then recast the value in other function to get int. Such as, int x = 89; and byte [] y;, the casting y=(byte[])x, not worked.
How can I do that ? What I have want,  for example :

```
                       in func1                          in func2
int x ;         x value is casted in the y        y is taken and x value is 
byte[] y;                                             extracted

       ------func1-----------  --------func2---------
       ^                    ^ ^                     ^
x = 33 ==feed into==> byte [] ===> extraction ===> 33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use types casts to do this kind of thing in Java.  These are *conversion*, and have to be done programatically.

For example:

```
    int input = ...
    byte[] output = new byte[4];
    output[0] = (byte) ((input >> 24) & 0xff);
    output[1] = (byte) ((input >> 16) & 0xff);
    output[2] = (byte) ((input >> 8) & 0xff);
    output[3] = (byte) (input & 0xff);
```

(There are more elegant ways of doing this particular conversion.)

Going from a `byte[]` to "something else" is similarly a conversion ... which may or may not be possible, depending on what the "something else" is.

For conversion back to an int:

```
    byte[] input = ... 
    int output = (input[0] << 24) | (input[1] << 16) | (input[2] << 8) | input[3]
```

---

This Q&A gives other ways to do this for `int` <-> `byte[]`: [Java integer to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array)

Comment: something else is int for my case. Is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(0xABABABAB);
byte[] arr = b.array();
```

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

```
byte[] arr = BigInteger.valueOf(0xABABABAB).toByteArray();
```

Comment: But my number is not in the form of 0xABABABAB.