# Java: How to split the integer(hex value) into byte array

Tags: java, int, hex, byte

I have an int in a hex value, the problem now how I can get each byte of it.

```
int hex = 0xDF60;
```

What I want is:

```
int byte1 = 0xDF;
int byte2 = 0x60;
```

Already refer the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array) question (Suggested by [talex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656904/talex) and [andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas)). But the result is not what I actually want:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(0x9F16).array();

for (byte b : bytes) {
   System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
}
```

Output:

```
0x00 0x00 0x-97 0x22
```

Assumed the output like that because the value is already in hex.

Thank you.

Comment: `int byte1 = hex >>> 8; int byte2 = (byte)hex;`

Comment: @shmosel thanks, I'll try using that.

Comment: @shmosel Already tested it, the output is `byte1: 223  byte2: 96` .

Comment: Yup, exactly like yours.