# RC4 Encryption/Decryption for integers Java

Tags: java, encryption, integer, rc4-cipher

In short, I have a integer value about 10 digits long. I would like to encrypt it using rc4 algorithm in Java. I went online and search, but I could only find encryption for string values/plaintext. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just convert the integer to a `String` and then encrypt the string?

1. `String myIntegerString = Integer.toString(myInteger)`;
2. encrypt `myIntegerString`;
3. store the encrypted `myIntegerString`;
4. read the encrypted `myIntegerString`;
5. decrypt `myIntegerString`;
6. `Integer.parseInt(myIntegerString)`.

Comment: Please try to format your answers to the best of your abilities. This one was so badly formatted and used invalid Java code that I was tempted to downvote instead of adjust. The answer would be greatly improved if you'd show encoding / decoding of the string as well.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the JavaSE API, in particular the `javax.crypto.Cipher` class. The encryption API is concerned with generic data, not interpreted in some way; this is why `Cipher#doFinal()` takes a byte array. (You may interpret that as a string, given the common terms "plaintext"/"ciphertext".)

The solution to your problem is to convert the integer to a byte array. If "integer" in your case means `int` (32-bit), then you need 4 bytes (8-bit). [See this question for (multiple good) solutions to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array)

Comment: Note that the max of `int` in Java is `2,147,483,647`. That's indeed 10 digits, but higher values than the given maximum will fail, i.e. a `long` (or larger things like `BigInteger`) may be required. Of course, you could still easily store that in 5 rather than 8 bytes where required.