# Get single bytes from multi-byte variable in java

Tags: java, c++, porting

How can I split a variable into single bytes in java? I have for example following snippet in C++:

```
    unsigned long someVar;
    byte *p = (byte*)(void*) someVar; // byte being typedef unsigned char (from 0 to 255)

    byte *bytes = new byte[sizeof(someVar)];

    for(byte i = 0;i<sizeof(someVar);i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = *p++;
    }

    .... //do something with bytes
```

I want to accomplish the same under java, but I can't seem to find an obvious workaround.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, absolutely true. Changed question.

Comment: Are you looking something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java

Comment: @Dinakar yes, sorry I didn't find it.

Comment: BTW, the question you ask is not quite well-defined: The result of your code will depend on the endianness of the platform it's running on (and on the platform's integer representation, and on the relative sizes of `char` and `long` - just to nitpick). Do you want the same in Java?

Comment: @sleske That's true, though I rarely program for other platforms different than windows. If possible I would like to have the same behaviour in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it with the [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class. One is to create a new byte array dynamically.

```
long   value = 123;
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(value).array();
```

Another is to write to an existing array.

```
long   value = 123;
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];

ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putLong(value);

// bytes now contains the byte representation of 123.
```

Comment: The question was a bit different: if you have some variable - how to access it in byte-by-byte manner

Comment: You can wrap a variable in a ByteBuffer and invoke get() which will return the value byte by byte.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed, as also pointed in the link provided in one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Guava, there is a convenience [Longs.toByteArray](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html#toByteArray%28long%29).  It is simply a wrapper for John's ByteBuffer answer above, but if you already use Guava, it's slightly "nicer" to read.