# How to convert a two bytes number in two indivudal numbers with 8 bits?

Tags: java

Suppose i have the number 520 that is mapped in two bytes that gives me the number: 1000001000 and i want to convert this number (520) to two other numbers, these numbers should be: 2 and 8 because 00000010 will give me 2 and 00001000 will give me 8. how can i do this with java?

Comment: The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java answer your question, and then some.

Comment: JLRishe's answer is technically correct, but the variable names are awful:  Conventional names would be `leastSignificantByte` or `lsb` instead of `oneNumber`, and `mostSignificantByte` or `msb` instead of `otherNumber`.  Conventional names, conventional style, conventional design patterns, etc. are like grease on the rails of your career path:  Obeying convention makes it much more likely that other developers will enjoy working with you and with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
int theNumber = 520;
byte oneNumber   = (byte)theNumber;
byte otherNumber = (byte)(theNumber >> 8);
```