# Convert int to byte array

Tags: java

I need a way to do this

```
String username = "Snake";
int usernameLength = username.length(); // 5
```

converting it to

```
0x05
```

Should I use a for loop to get each number and add a zero if the result is less than two numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java

Comment: And what do you mean by "encoding" for an *`int`*? Usually you only need encoding for a string.

Comment: So, you want to convert the length to its hexadecimal representation?

Comment: @dudeprgm That makes sense, sorry!

Comment: "...converting it to 0x05"  Converting _what_ to 0x05?  The length of the given string?  What is 0x05?  Do you mean the _String_ "0x05"?  Does the x mean hexadecimal?  What if the length was a much larger number?  What are the constraints on the length and format of the string?

Comment: @dudeprgm, No.  Integers are a datatype like any other that needs to be encoded when serialized or laid out in memory.  There are two different [endiannesses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) which are commonly used for fixed width integral types, and then there are [*varint* encodings](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints) which use a variable number of bytes per integer.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Ah, sorry. I just thought that when he was referring to a specific encoding, he was referring to String encodings, like UTF-8, etc. (From his comment, apparently he was but nevertheless, sorry for the mistake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `ByteBuffer` class...

```
byte[] byteArray = ByteBuffer.allocate(1).putInt(username.length()).array();
```

Comment: java.nio.BufferOverflowException is called. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that call to `allocate(1)` only allocates a single byte and you need at least 4 to call `putInt()`. My fault, sorry. Up that number to something larger and that should work.

Comment: Thanks. But this represents the size of the string with just bytes? I need to write the size of the string on the header of packet with only two bytes.

Comment: If you only need two bytes and you know your String won't be larger than that, you can either deal in shorts (`.putShort((short)username.length())`) and set the allocation to 2 (2 bytes). Or you can take the `array()` that gets returned and only use two bytes of it. None of this was clear at all in your question, by the way.

Comment: Thanks again. Got it working. Yeah, I was lost and didn't know how to explain it.