# Android | LSB & MSB

Tags: android, arrays, byte, endianness

I've got problem with LSB and MSB during sending request to the device. I need to send sessionId(int). It needs to be send on four bytes. Right now I'm sending byte array like this :
So , for example if sessionID is 14 I'm sending :

```
public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
        return new byte[] {
                (byte)(value >>> 24),
                (byte)(value >>> 16),
                (byte)(value >>> 8),
                (byte)value};
    }


byteData[36] - 0
byteData[37] - 0
byteData[38] - 0
byteData[39] - 14
```

The problem is - I need to set byteData[36] as LSB and byteData[39] as MSB. Could you help me with this ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936865/6950238) answer.

Comment: With this solution byteData[39] is still 14. I need value 14 to be on byteData[36]

Comment: Just use `ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN` instead of `ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN` order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer into byte array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java)

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936865/6950238) answer of [Gregory Pakosz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216063/gregory-pakosz) with `ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN` to `ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN` order change:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
b.putInt(14);
byte[] result = b.array();
```

In this case `b[0] == 14`.