# can't convert received UDP packet to int in java

Tags: java, string, int, udp, byte

I wrote a code to send and receive packet using UDP protocol. When I received `int`, and I'm sure it's a number, I can't convert it from `byte[]` - which is the type of received packet - to an `int`. I tried to convert it from `byte[]` to `String`, and from `String` to `int`, but the same problem, I got the exception "NumberFormatException". My code to convert is:

```
  String newtext = new String (receivePacket.getData());
  System.out.println("I receive "+ newtext );
  int location = Integer.parseInt(newtext);
```

The output shown in console is a number, but the code can't see as a number. Any suggestion to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

> the code can't see a number

This is completely meaningless as a problem description; however the problem is here:

```
String newtext = new String (receivePacket.getData());
```

This should be:

```
String newtext = new String (receivePacket.getData(),receivePacket.getOffset(),receivePacket.getLength());
```

However your description is so vague that it's possible you're receiving the `int` in binary, in which case you need the following instead:

```
int location = new DataInputStream((receivePacket.getData(),receivePacket.getOffset(),receivePacket.getLength()).readInt();
```

or possibly `readShort()`.

Comment: thank you for your reply and sorry for the vague in the explanation. Your suggestion doesn't solve my problem, but I think I know more about my problem, which is the when I use the different ways of converting, the whole `Byte[1024]` is converted, not just the `int`, which is the beginning of the array.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved using to steps:
1. The input `int` is converted to `Byte[4]` before sending the packet using this post [Convert integer into byte array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java)

2. Convert it back from `Byte[4]` to `int` using this post  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Date-Type/Convertabytearrayinteger4bytestoitsintvalue.htm

Thank you for who tried to help me, hope this help who face the same problem.

Comment: @EJP, the problem described correctly and the code I was posted is part of the problem.